# Color Option Theme Customizer API no Output

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get output from below setting but it is now working and displaying blank. When I try to `echo` in plan text then some times it appear in customizer mode. i'm using `<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'shoplabel_color' ); ?>` to Get output.
Is there anything which i'm missing like javascript or any?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('label_color',
        array(
            'default'           => '43AC6A',
            'type'              => 'theme_mod',
            'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
                       'sanitize_callback'  => 'theme_slug_sanitize_hex_color'
        ));


             $wp_customize->add_control(
                     new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'label_color',
                     array (

                         'settings'     => 'label_color',
                         'section'      => 'my_theme_page',

        'label'         => __( 'Label color', 'theme_slug' )


                     )  ));
```

Comment: Have you defined `theme_slug_sanitize_hex_color` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok resolve the issue problem in default function which i copied from chip code so now I write new function, It's working

```
function theme_slug_sanitize_hex_color( $color ) {
    if ( '' === $color )
        return '';

    // 3 or 6 hex digits, or the empty string.
    if ( preg_match('|^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$|', $color ) )
        return $color;

    return null;
}
```